# Why fuseki web UI does not show my dataset?

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki

I have config a assembler.ttl and started a fuseki server with it. the config file is as such:

```
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix :        <#> .

<#entities> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    fuseki:name                       "entities" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery               "sparql" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery               "query" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpdate              "update" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpload              "upload" ;   # Non-SPARQL upload service
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;     # SPARQL Graph store protocol (read and write)
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore      "get" ;      # SPARQL Graph store protocol (read only)
    fuseki:dataset                   <#dataset> ;
.

<#dataset> rdf:type      tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "/opt/someDir/entities" ;
    ja:context [ ja:cxtName "arq:queryTimeout" ;  ja:cxtValue "1000" ] ;
```

And when I use web UI to show datasets, it contains no datasets. And create a new dataset seems no trouble. The added dataset located in $FUSEKI_BASE/run/datasets. Is there anything I can do to let fuseki web UI recognize my dataset and allow me to do upload or so operation on it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your default graph is empty.. So it is obvious to have an empty DB on Web GUI.

This config.ttl should provide you a default graph structured as your TDB files.

```
@prefix :      <http://base/#> .
@prefix tdb:   <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix ja:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .

:service_tdb_all  a                   fuseki:Service ;
        rdfs:label                    "MyDataset" ;
        fuseki:dataset                :dataset ;
        fuseki:name                   "MyDataset" ;
        fuseki:serviceQuery           "query" , "sparql" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore  "get" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore
                "data" ;
        fuseki:serviceUpdate          "update" ;
        fuseki:serviceUpload          "upload" .

:dataset a ja:RDFDataset ;
    ja:defaultGraph <#tdbGraph>;
.

<#tdbGraph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB ;
    tdb:dataset :tdb_dataset_readwrite 
.

:tdb_dataset_readwrite  a             tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location  "$FUSEKI_BASE/run/datasets"
.
```

You may need to edit `tdb:location` and `:service_tdb_all` to suit your desiderata.

Comment: It gives me this exception:

org.apache.jena.sparql.ARQException: Found two matches: var ?root -> http://base/#dataset, http://base/#tdb_dataset_readwrite

Comment: Have you checked that your path doesnt correspond to two datasets?

Comment: If the problem is that it is empty, was  "<#dataset> tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ;" intended (query the union of all graphs)?